# Hawtio : Camel not showing all instances in the same JVM

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I have 10 Camel Components deployed in the same JVM as Hawtio.

Each of these is unique and has different ID.

I can see all 10 via the JMX view, but only 9 via the "Camel" view.

If I remove "1" I can see number "10", instead if I remove "3" I can see "10".

I can't find a reason why a camel route is not shown on the Camel page.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Can someone please give me some direction on how to fnd out the reason for this please.

I've tested on versions , 1.4.17 & 1.4.12

If I use Hawtio to "Destroy" Camel number 10, then it refreshes to show "01".

Comment: A user reported something similar, he said it worked with 1.4.4. Can you try that version to see if it works for you?

Comment: 1.4.4 didn't work, and I've tested 1.4.19 today and it also does not work.

Comment: This issue is also being tracked on GitHub : https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1513#issuecomment-55418297

Answer (score 2):

This helped me view all our routes in Hawtio:

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Not-all-processors-are-listed-in-JMX-preventing-detailed-route-statistics-profiling-tt5757634.html#a5757647

The solution is to go into HawtIO / Preferences / Jolokia, and change Max 
Collection Size from 500 (the default) up to a larger number.

Cheers

Comment: I have tried this, in my case I've got 20 simple web apps. I've created a tomcat with the 20 WARS for Clas to look at. I might have to ask him again nicely.